# Connecting 4-wires-resistive touchscreen with Simulink

Tags: c, matlab, arduino, simulink, touchscreen

I'm trying to connect my touchscreen via Simulink. My problem is, I don't get any actual values.

I connected my (Yin,Yout,Xin,Xout) of my touchscreen to following pins (A0,A1,A2,A3). I'm using an Arduino Mega2560.

My Simulink blocks do look like following (picture I.):

[image]

And my function in the block follows:

```
function [values_X, values_Y]  = Touch_screen_new(Yin, Yout, Xin, Xout)

 korrX = 1.2;
 korrY = 1.1;
 
 a = arduino();
   
  configurePin(a, 'A0', 'DigitalInput') 
  configurePin(a, 'A1', 'DigitalInput') 
  configurePin(a, 'A2', 'DigitalInput') 
  configurePin(a, 'A3', 'DigitalInput') 
 
    % Read X
    configurePin(a, 'A0', 'DigitalOutput') 
    configurePin(a, 'A1', 'DigitalOutput')
    writeDigitalPin(a,'A0',0);
    writeDigitalPin(a,'A1',1);  
    pause(0.005);
    
     % Read and store X
    values_X = readVoltage(a,'A2');
    values_X = (values_X - 507);
    values_X = (11.4*values_X/507)*korrX;
    
    % Reset Y
    writeDigitalPin(a,'A1', 0);
    pause(0.005); % Pause to allow lines to power down
    configurePin(a, 'A0', 'DigitalInput')
    configurePin(a, 'A1', 'DigitalInput')
    
    %~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    % Read Y
    %~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % Set X to a gradient
    configurePin(a, 'A2', 'DigitalOutput')
    configurePin(a, 'A3', 'DigitalOutput')
    writeDigitalPin(a, 'A2', 0);
    writeDigitalPin(a, 'A3', 1);
    pause(0.005); % Pause to allow lines to power up
  
    % Read and store Y
    values_Y = readVoltage(a,'A0');
    values_Y = (values_Y - 501);
    values_Y = (15.2*values_Y/501)*korrY;
    
    % Reset X
    writeDigitalPin(a, 'A3', 0);
    pause(0.005); % Pause to allow lines to power down
    configurePin(a, 'A2', 'DigitalInput')
    configurePin(a, 'A3', 'DigitalInput')
    pause(0.250);  
    %~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    % Output our values
    %~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    disp(values_X);
    disp(values_Y);
    
    
end
```

Now, is there a problem with my blocks or am I doing something wrong in the function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since we've got no information on your touchscreen [pins], this is just speculation. But, I'm not sure why (e.g.) `A2` is _both_ input and output. I'd think you'd want to read from `A2` and output to `A3` [or vice-versa], but _not_ flip pins between tristate/input and output.

Comment: You have recently asked several similar looking variants of this question, please consider taking a step back and thinking about why you might not be getting the answers you need. More directly, you are asking a broad question here, probably without enough context or info for us to provide an answer. Simplify and boil down your problem to something specific you are having an issue with. Perhaps a single pin, try with MATLAB code instead of MATLAB embedded in Simulink first, are you happy the `arduino` connection is working with a simpler peripheral, etc.